# ETL Process - Java Program Design Pattern

Tags: java, database, postgresql, design-patterns

I've got a project to do for my studies. It's an application that should do some kind of an ETL process. 
The basic concept is like that: 
 
1. There's some webpage which compares some electronic devices. I have to parse it's HTML to get some      data. I've already cover that up. I've used JSOUP library and it's working like charm. 
 
2. Than I load the date to some collection of my data type which is simple POJO. 
3. Third part is to load this data to the database but no records can be same.

**And there is where the problem starts**. 
 I don't know if **DAO** pattern will be fine, because so far I was using it to get data from the database not reverse. Or should I put there some **persistence** layer?
It's not big amount of data 100 records max, so I don't know if it won't be an overkill. 
If no persistence layer will JDBC be enough?

I want to make a PostgreSQL database.

The GUI is made in JavaFX and it's separated from the logic as much as possible, so it resemble MVC pattern.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Make it as simple as possible. This is a small app. Persistence layers and DAO patterns are for big systems, they are not really useful on such small scale.

Comment: Here is a [simple sample for accessing a database from JavaFX, using JDBC](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/4955598).